# FFMPEG / x264: can I use pass 1 from one encoding session as pass 2 for another?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, h.264, x264

#### Question:

Is it legal to use a "pass 1" encoding of a source video at one resolution/bitrate as the input to a "pass 2" encoding of the same source at a *different* resolution/bitrate? I tried it and it ***seeeeeeems*** to work, but am not at all certain it will in the general case: the stream profile (I/P/B frame choice, etc.) looks different from using the same parameters for both passes, but also looks "good enough".

I am at the point where I need an authoritative answer on this one.

#### Why *in tarnation* [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trr4m.png) would you do that?

Because two-pass encoding fixes a maddening bug in FFMPEG (x264, really) that probably won't get fixed any time soon: depending on the speed of your machine, the first ~1 second or so of video will often have a highly inappropriate bitrate. This is very easily reproduced with a high bitrate source stream transcoded to a low bitrate on a very fast machine (such as an *EC2 c4.8xlarge*). An idle i7 quadcore MacBook Pro *IS NOT* sufficient to reproduce this bug.

It will either be ***EXCEEDINGLY*** high:

- single pass CBR with no **VBV** specified

  (ignore the fact that CBR without a VBV *isn't CBR at all*)

or too low:

- single pass CBR with **VBV**
- single pass VBR: **QScale** with **VBV** and maxrate

Both VIFp and SSIM quality measurements show that the lower/high bitrates do indeed correspond to unnecessarily reduced/increased quality (i.e. the bitrate **should NOT** have been higher or lower).

Doing a two-pass CBR encoding works *great* and solves the problem...if you have the time for it. Unfortunately, I can't afford the latency of a two-pass encoding for a single resolution.

#### So what is it you want to do?

I am currently performing an initial transcode at a lower resolution (480). This will cover as many playback devices as possible. I would like to use that as my pass 1. Since 480 resolution sucks anyway, I can just post that pass 1 video as my 480, regardless of any silly bitrates in the first second of video.

I would then like to use *the 480 pass 1 info* and only do pass 2 on my higher resolutions. In the CBR/VBV case, this would be:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -pass 1 -vf  scale=852:480 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k ... 480.mp4
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -pass 2 -vf scale=1280:720 -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k ... 720.mp4
```

[image: Barney Google]

Comment: Can you please post the complete FFmpeg log ? I have a feeling your encodes use too many threads considering those low resolutions, which is detrimental to the quality.

Comment: What bug are you referring to?

Comment: Please see this link:
http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2296&p=6652

Comment: @Ely Hi, Ely! It's me, Mark! I am still not convinced that this is a thread issue, or perhaps are convinced that the too many thread issue is a red herring in that it merely enables the bug. Remember that at a high bitrate, I need a BUNCH of threads and very fast machines to ensure timely transcoding.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard (redone to give you an "at"/notification). Here's the URL that Ely and I had a discussion on: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2296&p=6652